# Validate Contact Form 7 to email address in Participant Database field

Tags: contact-form-7, filter-validate-email

We are using Contact Form 7 and the Participants Database plugin. We want to limit who is able to submit a "members only" contact form to email addresses that are in the wp_participants_database table.

Is there a way to validate the email address in the contact form with the email field in that table?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Solved it myself with help from Participants Database support. It could be used for other validation by changing the line that checks the database.

```
/***  Contact 7 filter to check Participants Database for member email ***/    

add_filter( 'wpcf7_validate_email*', 'email_in_participants_db', 20, 2 );

function email_in_participants_db( $result, $tag ) {    

// retrieve the posted email
$form  = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
$your_email = $form->get_posted_data('member-email');

// if  in database, validate 
// code from PD - Participants_Db::get_record_id_by_term($term, $value);
$member_id = Participants_Db::get_record_id_by_term( 'email', $your_email );

if( ! $member_id ) {
    $result->invalidate('member-email', 'That email address is not in the Member Directory. Please contact the Guild if you need to update it.'); 
    }
// return the filtered value
return $result;     
}
```